# JavaScript loop on loop and display details from two different URL

Tags: javascript, loops, url, dom

I'm looking to build an app that searches for a person by name - I have achieved this part - and displays the person name. The second part of the app should also present more details for each person on click (this information should be retrieved from a second URL. Lastly the app should also inject an image when I click on that person. I haven't been able to make this work.
Can you guy help fix this or shine a light?

I have commented out what I have been trying to do.

https://codepen.io/edmonteiro/pen/qKeMLj

```
document.getElementById("subBtn").onclick = function(event){
//prevent default submission
event.preventDefault();

//grab the typed value in the text box
var name = document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].value;

//Alternatively give an "id" attribute to the text box in the HTML
//for example, <input type="text" name="textboxname" class="name">, use:
//var name = document.getElementById("textboxname").value();

let ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

//pass this search value as a parameter in URL to get results from database
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://izrite.com:5555/leads?page=1&name=' + name, true);

//function to call when the AJAX request is completed
ourRequest.onload = function(){
//if request completed successfully
if(ourRequest.status === 200){
  let ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);

  let list = document.getElementById("list");

  //process only if request returned a valid JSON data
  if(typeof ourData === 'object'){
    //if there are 1 or more results found
    if(ourData.length > 0){
      list.innerHTML = "<p><b>Matched names from database:</b></p>";

      //for each `lead` in the array, print its name
      for(lead of ourData){
        list.innerHTML += "<p>Name: " + lead.name + "</p>";
      /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
      /* Second and third part of the test - to be continued. Not finished before the 5hours time frame mentioned on the challenge specs*/
        // if((lead.id).value()==="0009bd06-a9ce-470e-b13a-acd2aaaa42d4"){
        //   let ourRequest2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //   ourRequest2.open('GET', 'https://izrite.com:5555/lead/0009bd06-a9ce-470e-b13a-acd2aaaa42d4', true);

        //   let moreDetails = document.getElementById('moreDetails');
        //   let ourData2 = JSON.parse(ourRequest2.responseText);
        //   if(typeof ourData2 === 'object'){
        //     //if there are 1 or more results found
        //     if(ourData2.length > 0){
        //       moreDetails.innerHTML = "<p><b>More details</b></p>";

        //       //for each `lead` in the array, print its name
        //       for(detl of ourData2){
        //         moreDetails.innerHtml += "<p>Name: " + detl.name + "</p><br><p>Make: " + detl.make + "</p><br><p>Model: " + detl.model + "</p><br><p>Derivative: " + detl.derivative + "</p>";

        //         // var myImage = new Image(100, 200);
        //         // myImage.src = 'https://izrite.com:5555/image/71890';
        //         // document.body.appendChild(myImage);
        //       }
        //     }
        //   }
        // }
        // ourRequest2.send();
      /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

      };
    }else{
      //no results found for this search query
      list.innerHTML = "<p><b>No match found in database!</b></p>";
    }
  }else{
    //response not in JSON format
    list.innerHTML = "<p><b>Response is not in valid JSON format!</b></p>";
  }
 }
}

 //send the AJAX request
 ourRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: Do I need to get a second onload function to the above code?